# How to jump to a mark using Elisp

Tags: mark, mark-ring

Suppose I store the current mark into a variable using `mark` or `(mark-marker)`. Then I move point elsewhere and insert some text. Which function should I use to jump to the saved mark?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save the mark as a marker:

```el
(setq my-var (mark-marker))
```

Then:

```el
(goto-char my-var)
```

This works regardless of the buffer where you set the variable to the marker:

```el
(let ((buf  (marker-buffer foo)))
  (switch-to-buffer buf)(goto-char foo))
```

Or if you want to go to that place temporarily, in Lisp code (i.e., without switching to that buffer):

```el
(with-current-buffer (marker-buffer foo)
  (goto-char foo))
```

Comment: I opened a C++ file and run `(mark-marker)` but it returns `#<marker in no buffer>`, while some other buffers the marks do have buffers. Do you know when does this happen?

Comment: @TuDo From what I understand, you need to set the mark first. Try doing `(push-mark)` and then `(mark-marker)`.

Answer (score 2):

The `goto-char` function works. It will teleport you to the mark in the same buffer.

```
(goto-char (mark))
```